# jasmine how to cover testcases for object literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

In my code is object literal. How to cover test cases using jasmine.
My sample code for below,

```
var objLiteral = {
   foo: function() {
      return bar;
   }
};
```

I tried the following test case using Jasmine.
testcase 1:

```
var tape = jasmine.createSpyObj(objLiteral, ['foo']);
tape.foo();
expect(tape.foo.calls.any()).toEqual(true);
```

testcase 2:

```
spyOn(objLiteral, 'foo');
objLiteral.foo();
expect(objLiteral.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Note: Both test cases are passed without any error. But code is not covered.

Comment: spyOn(objLiteral, 'foo').and.callThrough();
objLiteral.foo();
expect(objLiteral.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
Ths is worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above code creates a spy object. So the real object and the actual function is not getting invoked.Hence, the code is not covered with the test.